# Spring filed with date/time is null when the form is submited

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jpa

I have a two mappings in my Controller. This is a GET mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/items/book-list/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showEditBookPage(@RequestParam Long id, ModelMap model){
    Book book = bookService.findBookById(id);
    model.addAttribute("editForm", book);
    LOG.info("Logged modified date once page is loaded: " + book.getModifyDate());
    return "admin/book";
}
```

This mapping is just for displaying a book.jsp page with small form.

I have also another mapping for the same value but with POST method, used to submit the form.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/items/book-list/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateBook(@ModelAttribute("editForm") @Valid Book bookForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "/admin/book";
    }

    LOG.info("Logged modified date before Save object: " + bookForm.getModifyDate());
    LOG.info("Logged author before Save object: " + bookForm.getAuthor());

    bookService.saveBook(bookForm);

    LOG.info("Logged modified date after Save object: " + bookForm.getModifyDate());
    LOG.info("Logged author after Save object: " + bookForm.getAuthor());

    return "admin/book";
}
```

My book.jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="editForm" >
        <div class="row border py-4">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <spring:bind path="title">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:label path="title" for="title">Book title</form:label>
                        <form:input path="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" cssErrorClass="form-control border border-danger"/>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="author">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:label path="author" for="author">Author</form:label>
                        <form:input path="author" type="text" class="form-control" id="author" cssErrorClass="form-control border border-danger"/>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <p class="form-group">Last modified date: ${editForm.modifyDate}</p>

            </div>
    </form:form>
```

Book entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
@NotEmpty(message = "This field is required.")
private String title;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int quantity;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int availability;

@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime modifyDate;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name="create_date", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime createDate;
```

Log from GET method:

```
2019-07-24 14:32:57.065 DEBUG 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.availability as availabi2_0_0_, book0_.create_date as create_d3_0_0_, book0_.modify_date as modify_d4_0_0_, book0_.quantity as quantity5_0_0_, book0_.title as title6_0_0_, book0_.author as author7_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.availability as availabi2_0_0_, book0_.create_date as create_d3_0_0_, book0_.modify_date as modify_d4_0_0_, book0_.quantity as quantity5_0_0_, book0_.title as title6_0_0_, book0_.author as author7_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
2019-07-24 14:32:57.068 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [10003]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.072 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([availabi2_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [56]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.072 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([create_d3_0_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-07-24T14:32:47.161]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.073 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([modify_d4_0_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-07-24 14:32:47.161]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.073 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([quantity5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [56]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.073 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([title6_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Book title]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.073 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([author7_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Philippa Gregory]
2019-07-24 14:32:57.078  INFO 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.s.s.web.controller.AdminController     : Logged modified date once page is loaded: 2019-07-24 14:32:47.161
```

Log from POST method

```
2019-07-24 14:34:12.840 DEBUG 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.availability as availabi2_0_0_, book0_.create_date as create_d3_0_0_, book0_.modify_date as modify_d4_0_0_, book0_.quantity as quantity5_0_0_, book0_.title as title6_0_0_, book0_.author as author7_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.availability as availabi2_0_0_, book0_.create_date as create_d3_0_0_, book0_.modify_date as modify_d4_0_0_, book0_.quantity as quantity5_0_0_, book0_.title as title6_0_0_, book0_.author as author7_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
2019-07-24 14:34:12.840 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [10003]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([availabi2_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [56]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([create_d3_0_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-07-24T14:32:47.161]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([modify_d4_0_0_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-07-24 14:32:47.161]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([quantity5_0_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [56]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([title6_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Book title]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.841 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([author7_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Philippa Gregory]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.843  INFO 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.s.s.web.controller.AdminController     : Logged modified date before Save object: null
2019-07-24 14:34:12.843  INFO 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.s.s.web.controller.AdminController     : Logged author before Save object: Book title 2
2019-07-24 14:34:12.874 DEBUG 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update book set availability=?, modify_date=?, quantity=?, title=?, author=? where id=?
Hibernate: update book set availability=?, modify_date=?, quantity=?, title=?, author=? where id=?
2019-07-24 14:34:12.876 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [56]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.877 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Jul 24 14:34:12 CEST 2019]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.877 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [56]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.877 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Book title 2]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.878 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [Philippa Gregory]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.878 TRACE 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [10003]
2019-07-24 14:34:12.884  INFO 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.s.s.web.controller.AdminController     : Logged modified date after Save object: null
2019-07-24 14:34:12.885  INFO 16119 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.s.s.web.controller.AdminController     : Logged author after Save object: Book title 2
```

When the form is submitted then "modifyDate" field is null while "title" is ok. Someone can explain to me why? This is shown in the console log.

View:

[Before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuKHD.png)

[After submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bCy.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a deserializer for that `LocalDateTime` field explicitly:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)  
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name="create_date", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime createDate;
```

And your deserializing class:

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // parse the String date into LocalDateTime object as it fits you
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add modify_date field in the My book.jsp: because only field date will post because it is new request and all old fields that you save in the model will not go with request. so there are two options add input text field to change the date.

or you will set the date manually before saving the

```
 bookForm.setModifyDate(new Date());
 bookService.saveBook(bookForm);
```

or you can also add @UpdateTimestamp if you want to currant local date and time

```
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime modifyDate;
```

Comment: Hi! Hm but I already have annotation @UpdateTimestamp above my modifyDate field. This date is correctly saved in database, but it is not visible in model/view. I have a workaround like this: after bookService.saveBook(bookForm); I can add a new modelAttribute like this: model.addAttribute("modifyDate",bookService.findBookById(bookForm.getId()).getModifyDate()); and this works. But don't understand why "TITLE" is not null but "MODIFYDATE" is.

Comment: Is this line of code are not working
<p class="form-group">Last modified date: ${editForm.modifyDate}</p>

Comment: Did you implements Serializable interface in your book entity if you did not implement please implement it and than check

Answer (score 0):

```
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime modifyDate;
```

This will do the job

Comment: I already have this annotation. Sorry I changed LocalDateTime to Date just for test but result is the same. I have updated a code in question.